# Tallying values in single column and separating into Rows in R

Tags: r

I have a single row of numbers. I'm wondering how I can separate it out so that it outputs columns that total the tally of each set of numbers. I've tried playing around with "separate" but I can't figure out how to make it work.

```
Here's my data frame:


2
2
2
2
2
4
4
4   

I'd like it to be

2  4
5  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `table()` function.

```
> df
  V1
1  2
2  2
3  2
4  2
5  2
6  4
7  4
8  4
> table(df$V1)

2 4 
5 3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tabulate` which would be faster

```
tabulate(factor(df1$V1))
#[1] 5 3
```